# Dropdown with numbers from 1 - 10 and total price below must change

Tags: javascript, html, contacts, contact-form-7

I am trying to create a drop down with numbers from 1 - 10 for example. Once a number is selected, it should change the total amount. However I have not succeeded and not sure what else I should do, please help.

I have got something put together so far.

```
<div class="checkout">
<input type="number" name="quantity" placeholder="How many would you like to order? (numeric numbers only)" class="quantity price" data-price="49" value="">
<p class="total" style='margin-bottom: 0px;' >Total: <span id="total">R49 per month</span></p>
</div>



<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".checkout").on("keyup", ".quantity", function(){
        var price = +$(".price").data("price");
        var quantity = +$(this).val();
        $("#total").text("R" + price * quantity);
    })
})

var foo = document.getElementById('.checkout');
foo.addEventListener('focus', function () {
    foo.setAttribute('data-value', this.value);
    this.value = '';
});
foo.addEventListener('blur', function () {
    if (this.value === '')
        this.value = this.getAttribute('data-value');
});
</script>
```

All I need is to change the type from a number to a drop down.

Comment: What's the issue ? Any error ? We aren't here to do anybody's homework. I think SO should not promote this kind of questions and should introduce a new flag for these I guess.

Comment: I have tried multiple ways on how to add a drop down, I am not asking for homework to be done, I am just asking for some help, because i am not sure how to change it from typing the number in to rather selecting the number